# Java Swing Layout block

Tags: java, layout

I'm trying to learn about layouts as I've read things about bad practice to use null layout with absolute positioning in GUI. If takes away the flexibility to expand the GUI dynamically. So I'm trying out some combinations of GUI blocks and now I've encounter a problem. Below is the GUI block I intend to try out:

[image]

I start off by doing the top part (block 1, 2 & 3) of the GUI and it works with the following code:

[image]

```
public class LayoutTestGuiDelegate implements Observer{
    private LayoutTestModel model;
    private int totalScreenWidth;
    private int totalScreenHeight;
    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JPanel totalScreen;
    private JPanel topScreen;
    private JPanel botScreen;
    private JPanel dateScreen;
    private ImagePanelOne imagePanelOne;
    private ImagePanelTwo imagePanelTwo;
    private ImagePanelThree imagePanelThree;
    private ImagePanelFour imagePanelFour;
    private ImagePanelFive imagePanelFive;

public LayoutTestGuiDelegate(LayoutTestModel model){
    this.model = model;
    totalScreenWidth = model.GetScreenWidth();
    totalScreenHeight = model.GetScreenHeight();
    SetupComponents();
}

public void SetupComponents(){  
    // set it to full exclusive mode
    final GraphicsDevice fullScreen = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
    mainFrame = new JFrame("Video Clock Display");
    mainFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1, 0, 0));
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainFrame.setUndecorated(true); // Remove title bar
    mainFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(false);    // Always on top
    mainFrame.setResizable(false);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);

    totalScreen = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1, 0, 0));
    mainFrame.setContentPane(totalScreen);

    topScreen = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2, 0, 0));
    imagePanelOne = new ImagePanelOne(model, 1020, 280);
    topScreen.add(imagePanelOne);

    dateScreen = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1, 0, 0));
    imagePanelTwo = new ImagePanelTwo(model, 900, 150);
    dateScreen.add(imagePanelTwo);
    imagePanelThree = new ImagePanelThree(model, 900, 130);
    dateScreen.add(imagePanelThree);
    topScreen.add(dateScreen);
    totalScreen.add(topScreen);

    mainFrame.pack();
}

@Override
public void update(Observable arg0, Object arg1) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            imagePanelOne.repaint();
            imagePanelTwo.repaint();
            imagePanelThree.repaint();
            imagePanelFour.repaint();
            imagePanelFive.repaint();
        }
    });

}

}
```

When I try to add in the bottom part (block 4 & 5), everything just go wierd. It shows up like this with the following code:

[image]

```
public class LayoutTestGuiDelegate implements Observer{
    private LayoutTestModel model;
    private int totalScreenWidth;
    private int totalScreenHeight;
    private JFrame mainFrame;
    private JPanel totalScreen;
    private JPanel topScreen;
    private JPanel botScreen;
    private JPanel dateScreen;
    private ImagePanelOne imagePanelOne;
    private ImagePanelTwo imagePanelTwo;
    private ImagePanelThree imagePanelThree;
    private ImagePanelFour imagePanelFour;
    private ImagePanelFive imagePanelFive;

public LayoutTestGuiDelegate(LayoutTestModel model){
    this.model = model;
    totalScreenWidth = model.GetScreenWidth();
    totalScreenHeight = model.GetScreenHeight();
    SetupComponents();
}

public void SetupComponents(){  
    // set it to full exclusive mode
    final GraphicsDevice fullScreen = GraphicsEnvironment.getLocalGraphicsEnvironment().getDefaultScreenDevice();
    mainFrame = new JFrame("Video Clock Display");
    mainFrame.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1, 0, 0));
    mainFrame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    mainFrame.setUndecorated(true); // Remove title bar
    mainFrame.setAlwaysOnTop(false);    // Always on top
    mainFrame.setResizable(false);
    mainFrame.setVisible(true);

    totalScreen = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1, 0, 0));
    mainFrame.setContentPane(totalScreen);

    topScreen = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2, 0, 0));
    imagePanelOne = new ImagePanelOne(model, 1020, 280);
    topScreen.add(imagePanelOne);

    dateScreen = new JPanel(new GridLayout(2, 1, 0, 0));
    imagePanelTwo = new ImagePanelTwo(model, 900, 150);
    dateScreen.add(imagePanelTwo);
    imagePanelThree = new ImagePanelThree(model, 900, 130);
    dateScreen.add(imagePanelThree);
    topScreen.add(dateScreen);
    totalScreen.add(topScreen);

    botScreen = new JPanel(new GridLayout(1, 2, 0, 0));
    imagePanelFour = new ImagePanelFour(model, 1420, 800);
    botScreen.add(imagePanelFour);
    imagePanelFive = new ImagePanelFive(model, 500, 800);
    botScreen.add(imagePanelFive);

    totalScreen.add(botScreen);
    mainFrame.pack();
}

@Override
public void update(Observable arg0, Object arg1) {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
        public void run() {
            imagePanelOne.repaint();
            imagePanelTwo.repaint();
            imagePanelThree.repaint();
            imagePanelFour.repaint();
            imagePanelFive.repaint();
        }
    });

}

}
```

Can Anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: Just a quick comment: the Java tutorials now recommend that you use a GUI builder like the one built into NetBeans IDE.  It's far far easier to use than trying to build complicated layouts by hand.  Docs: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/using.html

Comment: I see, I was looking for Windows Builder but my eclipse neon couldn't download and install it. So I had to do it the hard way. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should use a `BorderLayout`.  Put the first three components in the `NORTH` constraint area.  Put 4 in the center, and put 5 in the `EAST`.

The example below doesn't look exactly like your picture, because the various panels I used have different borders and layouts by default, and the buttons I used as examples are pretty small.  But overall I think this is going to be the easiest to work with if you have to do this by hand.

I'd also like to see you use smaller panels divided into smaller classes, and compose your GUI from those smaller components.  The rather large blob of code you have above is kind of unwieldy and hard to read.

```
public class LayoutTest
{
   public static void main( String[] args )
   {
      SwingUtilities.invokeLater( new Runnable(){
         public void run()
         {
            JFrame frame = new JFrame();

            TopPanel top = new TopPanel();
            frame.add( top, BorderLayout.NORTH );
            frame.add( new JButton( "4" ) );
            frame.add( new JButton( "5" ), BorderLayout.EAST );

            frame.pack();
            frame.setDefaultCloseOperation( JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE );
            frame.setLocationRelativeTo( null );
            frame.setVisible( true );
         }
      } );
   }
}

class CenterButtonPanel extends JPanel {
   public CenterButtonPanel( String name ) {
      JButton but = new JButton( name );
      add( but );
   }
}

class TopPanel extends JPanel {
  TopPanel() {
     Box right = Box.createVerticalBox();
     right.add( new CenterButtonPanel( "2" ) );
     right.add( new CenterButtonPanel( "3" ) );
     Box left = Box.createHorizontalBox();
     left.add( new CenterButtonPanel( "1" ) );
     left.add( right );
     add( left );
  }
}
```

Comment: I'll try it out and let you know. Thanks :D

Comment: It worked!! I tried using Box and borderLayout and it did what I wanted. Thanks!!